# Responsive Table in Email Template not working in case of mobile view while checking in mobile through email

Tags: css, html

Please help me out in getting proper view in case of mobile view while code is sent through an extension to gmail account and then checking in mobile.

Here is my complete code :
I'm trying to get mobile view as shown in figure1 i.e.,[mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARlhg.png)
but when i'm checking it in mobile only the width of the table is getting adjusted but not getting as shown in above image.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>1973 Online</title>
<style>
/* Element selectors */
body {
    width: 100% !important;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #f8f8f8
}
img {
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    display: block;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
span {font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif;}
a {text-decoration: none !important;color: #00A1DD}
.white {text-decoration: none !important;color: #ffffff !important;}
.black {text-decoration: none !important;color: #000000 !important;}
.red {text-decoration: none !important;color: #e53e2f !important;}
.appleLinks a {color: #000000;text-decoration: none}
.appleLinksWhite a {color: #ffffff;text-decoration: none}

@media only screen and (max-width: 495px) {

    /*Hide*/
table[class="hide"] {display: none !important}
tr[class="hide"] {display: none !important;}
td[class="hide"] {display: none !important;}
img[class="hide"] { display: none !important;}
span[class="hide"] {display: none !important;}

table[class="table40"] {width: 44% !important; font-size: 12px !important}

table[class="table40"] td {padding: 6px !important}

table[class="table60"] {width: 56% !important;}

td[class="heromob"] {background:url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/seagateglobal/2016/2016-01-18-NASPortfolio/images/20160118-NASPortfolio-heroimage-mob.jpg) no-repeat center #098fc9 !important; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 10px !important; padding-left: 0px !important; text-align: center}

td[class="center-text"] {text-align:center !important}  
}


</style>
</head>

<body>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="font-size: 20px; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif; color:#333333">
    <tr>
        <td style="font-size:0px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="600" align="center" style="font-size:0px">

        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0" style="font-size: 20px; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif; color:#333333" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <tr>
              <td width="600" height="15" bgcolor="#e1e1e1" style="height:15px; line-height:15px; font-size:0px">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td bgcolor="#e1e1e1">

              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td width="30">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td valign="bottom">

                    <table width="23%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" align="left" bgcolor="#919292" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif; color:#ffffff; mso-hide:all" class="table40">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td bgcolor="#e1e1e1" align="center" style="color:#e1e1e1">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #b4b4b4;color:#FFFFFF">Category 1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #b4b4b4;color:#FFFFFF">Category 2</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #b4b4b4;color:#FFFFFF">Category 3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF">Category 4</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>                    

                    <!--[if mso]>
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" align="left" bgcolor="#919292" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif; color:#ffffff" class="table40">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td bgcolor="#e1e1e1" align="center" style="color:#e1e1e1">&nbsp;</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #b4b4b4">Workload Rate</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #b4b4b4">Internal Data Rate</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #b4b4b4">MTBF</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center">Limited Warranty</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <![endif]-->


                    <!--[if mso]></td><td><![endif]-->

                    <table width="25%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" align="left" bgcolor="#6fbcde" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif; color:#ffffff; mso-hide:all" class="table60">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td bgcolor="#e1e1e1" align="center" style="color:#919292"><strong>Title</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #b4b4b4;color:#FFFFFF">180TB/Year</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #b4b4b4;color:#FFFFFF">159-216MB/s</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #b4b4b4;color:#FFFFFF">1 million hours</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF">3 years</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <!--[if mso]>
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" align="left" bgcolor="#6fbcde" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif; color:#ffffff;" class="table60">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td bgcolor="#e1e1e1" align="center" style="color:#919292">Title</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #b4b4b4">180TB/Year</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #b4b4b4">159-216MB/s</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #b4b4b4">1 million hours</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center">3 years</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <![endif]-->

                    <!--[if mso]></td><td style="display:none"><![endif]-->

                    <table width="0%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" bgcolor="#919292" style="font-size: 0px; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif; color:#ffffff; mso-hide:all" class="table40">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td bgcolor="#e1e1e1" align="center" style="color:#e1e1e1"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #b4b4b4;color:#FFFFFF">Category 1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #b4b4b4;color:#FFFFFF">Category 2</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #b4b4b4;color:#FFFFFF">Category 3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF">Category 4</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <!--[if mso]></td><td><![endif]-->

                    <table width="25%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" align="left" bgcolor="#199cd4" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif; color:#ffffff; mso-hide:all" class="table60">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td bgcolor="#e1e1e1" align="center" style="color:#919292"><strong>Title</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #b4b4b4;color:#FFFFFF">300TB/Year</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #b4b4b4;color:#FFFFFF">216-230MB/s</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #b4b4b4;color:#FFFFFF">1.2 million hours</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF">5 years</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <!--[if mso]>
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" align="left" bgcolor="#199cd4" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif; color:#ffffff" class="table60">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td bgcolor="#e1e1e1" align="center" style="color:#919292"><strong>Title</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #b4b4b4">300TB/Year</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #b4b4b4">216-230MB/s</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #b4b4b4">1.2 million hours</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center">5 years</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <![endif]-->

                    <!--[if mso]></td><td style="display:none"><![endif]-->

                    <table width="0%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" bgcolor="#919292" style="font-size: 0px; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif; color:#ffffff; mso-hide:all" class="table40">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td bgcolor="#e1e1e1" align="center" style="color:#e1e1e1"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                                              <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #b4b4b4;color:#FFFFFF">Category 1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #b4b4b4;color:#FFFFFF">Category 2</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #b4b4b4;color:#FFFFFF">Category 3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF">Category 4</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <!--[if mso]></td><td><![endif]-->

                    <table width="25%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" align="left" bgcolor="#0c619d" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif; color:#ffffff; mso-hide:all" class="table60">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td bgcolor="#e1e1e1" align="center" style="color:#919292"><strong>Title</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #b4b4b4;color:#FFFFFF">550TB/Year</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #b4b4b4;color:#FFFFFF">Up to 237MB/s</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #b4b4b4;color:#FFFFFF">2 million hours</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF">5 years</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <!--[if mso]>
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" align="left" bgcolor="#0c619d" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif; color:#ffffff" class="table60">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td bgcolor="#e1e1e1" align="center" style="color:#919292"><strong>Title</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #b4b4b4">550TB/Year</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #b4b4b4">Up to 237MB/s</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #b4b4b4">2 million hours</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center">5 years</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <![endif]-->

                    </td>
                    <td width="30">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>

              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td bgcolor="#e1e1e1" height="15" style="height:15px; line-height:15px; font-size:0px">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>            

        </td>
        <td style="font-size:0px">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>

I need to get as shown in the below image in case of mobile view:
[mobileview][1]

And in case of desktop i'll be getting as shown in below image:
[desktopview][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpRCm.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpY5u.png
```